# Is Custom Kibana plugin installation in AWS ElasticSearch possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Does anybody know whether it is possible to install a custom plugin for Kibana in AWS ElasticSearch instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heard from AWS support that it is not supported (installation of any plugin in ES or Kibana for that matter is not supported). A workaround suggested was to install a Kibana separately and to point to ES service endpoint.

Comment: Were you able to successfully create a separate Kibana instance and point it at the AWS Elasticsearch instance? I am trying to do this and I am having issues figuring out how to get Kibana to authenticate to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @ivan I ended up going for setting up my own ES instance (I needed to install ES custom plugin as well - not so sure that's supported now).